# Synchronous access to queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement where I will hit a link and get a response. The response is an XML data containing child links. The response is then copied to a file and the child links are added to a queue where I then iteratively have to hit the child links until there are no further children.

I first did this using a single queue. But since it slow, I tried to implement a executor. I do not have to maintain the order of the data. This is my approach now :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.AbstractQueue;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Hierarchy2 {

    private static AbstractQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private static FileWriter writer;
    private static XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        writer = new FileWriter(new File("hierarchy.txt"));
        String baseUrl = "my url goes here";

        queue.add(baseUrl);

        int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            executor.execute(new QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler));
        }

        executor.shutdown();

    }
}

class QueueProcess implements Runnable {

    private AbstractQueue<String> queue;
    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private URL url;
    private FileWriter writer;
    private SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    private SAXParser saxParser;
    private XMLHandler xmlHandler;

    public QueueProcess(AbstractQueue<String> queue, FileWriter writer, XMLHandler xmlHandler) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.writer = writer;

        this.xmlHandler = xmlHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            while (true) {
                String link = queue.poll();
                if (link != null) {
                    if (queue.size() >= 500) {
                        System.out.println("here" + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        getChildLinks(link);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(link + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        queue.addAll(getChildLinks(link));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private List<String> getChildLinks(String link) throws IOException, SAXException {
        url = new URL(link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())).lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        saxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()), xmlHandler);
        List<String> urlList = xmlHandler.getURLList();

        writer.write(result + System.lineSeparator());

        connection.disconnect();
        return urlList;
    }

}
```

The code throws a NPE is some places. That needs to be fixed which I will. However, is a concurrent access to the FileWriter right ?

Please tell me if this code is right in achieving what I really want to do. Also improvements/suggestions on making it further efficient are appreciated.

Comment: You'll receive better reviews if you show a complete example.  For example, I recommend that you [edit] to show the necessary `import` lines, and a `main()` that shows how to call your function.  It's not mandatory, but it really helps!

Comment: I see only one thread invoked in one `execute()` call in the main method. where is the loop or some other place where the rest of the tasks are invoked??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher my bad, edited the question

Comment: @TobySpeight added the imports !

Comment: if all the queue processes get the same args, they will all do the same work, won't they? you have to **split** the work among the processes

Comment: No, actually the queue is loaded with new links everytime the code runs. Hence it will be shared. Only the classes that do not change are being sent as args.

Comment: i see.  the point I see now is that if the queue is empty the code will loop right back to check the queue so the queue is bombarded. it is customery to have the thread sleep for some time before checking again. perhaps 1 second?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the concern about the concurrent access to FileWriter if only because you rely on this class to be thread safe.  a quick google showed me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972549/threads-and-file-writing) and it seems (on the surface) that this is not correct assumption.

I would design This differently, although I do not know if the new design is faster: I would have the tasks only do the url look up.  This is based on the assumption that this is the bottleneck in the whole process (seems reasonable to me...)

So each task gets a url from the queue, does the lookup, gets the response string, parse into xml doc and put that into a separate xml-response-queue.  the main method is responsible for listening to the xml-response-queue, doing the file writing and populating the url queue with child links.

Comment: This approach sounds great but the problem is loading the child links. I need to write the response to a file and the child links from the response back to the queue. That's why I have both the logic in the task itself.Also another requirement is to write only 500 responses to the file. The next set of responses should be written in a new file.

Comment: so the tasks write the responses as is to the output queue. the main method can write the responses to the file, check for any limitations regarding the file, etc. and then parse the response and get the child links

Comment: how can the task queue stop its iteration after all the child links are read, ie now I use a `while(true)`, to iterate , if I use `while(!queue.isEmpty())` , then only one task will be processing since all the other threads will find the queue empty and will finish.

Comment: good question.  one answer that springs to mind is at the end of processing, the main method will add a dummy entry to the queue (for example, "END") and the task wlil get the msg, re-insert it to the queue (for the next task to read) and exit.

Comment: yes, this idea might work for the end of the links. But the problem arises when I start it in the first place. when I add the base url to the task and start it, before it can process the child links of the base url, the other tasks find the queue empty and then exit leaving only one thread to process all the links - which is the thread on which the base url was added.

Comment: basically my requirement is a multiple producer, multiple consumer concept.

Comment: I didn't say the exit condition should change. I see no need for it to change. if the requirement forces design, this should be included in the question!!